# How to retry a Cloud Firestore transaction in a Cloud Function until state == true

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

## The issue

I have a Cloud Function which updates a Cloud Firestore document, based on changes in a document `state` field.  These updates **must** happen in a particular order.  When two changes are made in quick succession, there's no guarantee that the Cloud Functions will run in the correct sequence.  Is there a way to have a Cloud Firestore transaction retry until it succeeds or times out?

1. `Document.state` is set to `stage1`
2. `Document.state` is updated to `stage2`
3. `Document.state` is updated to `stage3`
4. Cloud Function is triggered and reads `stage3`
5. Cloud Function is triggered and reads `stage2`

In the Cloud Functions documentation, it discusses the ability to retry transactions on failure.  However, this option is greyed out in the Cloud Functions section of the GCP Console (not shown in the Firebase Console)

## Sample code

### Variables passed in

```
myDocumentRef: db.doc('myCollection/myDocument')
newState: stage3
```

### Transaction code

```
var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(myDocumentRef)
        .then(doc => {
            if ((newState = 'stage2' && doc.data().state = 'stage1') ||
                (newState = 'stage3' && doc.data().state = 'stage2')) {
              t.update(myDocumentRef, { population: newPopulation });
            } else {
              // Keep retrying the transaction until it succeeds
            }
        });
}).then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Firestore transactions retry themselves by default.  [The documentation for transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) states:

> A transaction consists of any number of get() operations followed by
>   any number of write operations such as set(), update(), or delete().
>   In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire
>   transaction again. For example, **if a transaction reads documents and
>   another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore
>   retries the transaction.** This feature ensures that the transaction
>   runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

This retry takes the form of repeated invocations of the transaction handler function (the function you pass to runTransaction).

The Cloud Functions retry mechanism is different.  It retries functions that don't fully successfully.  The details about how that works can be read [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries).  It has nothing to do with Firestore transactions.  The semantics of those retries are independent of the type of trigger used.

Comment: Hey Doug.  Thanks for the clarification.  However, the issue isn't the transactions running concurrently.  They run out of sequence.  How can I get my transaction code to exit and retry, if a condition is not met?

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't give you any guarantees about the sequence of events.  Bear in mind that your code could be running on any number of servers, and getting them to all observe some sequence would make the server not scale like it should.

Comment: Yes.  I understand that.  What I want to know, is if there's a way to have a transaction retry if a condition is not met?  Then if another function writes the data, while the first transaction retrying, it will eventually succeed (once the condition is met)

Comment: No, that's not the way transactions work.  Transaction handlers should never be relying on external data or conditions that may change.  They should only work static data and the documents that are being read in the transaction.

Comment: So, `t.get(myDocumentRef)` reads the document and I want to check the value of the `state` field.  If it is not what I'm expecting, I want the transaction to fail and repeat until it does equal what I'm expecting.  It is being read by the transaction as `state: 0`.  I want it to be `state: 1` before I continue.  Another function is also trying to change it from 0 to 1..  I want the other function to write 1, before this transaction changes it to 2.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks, Doug for your input.  I'll either redesign how my application works or I might try wrapping the transaction in a do...while loop and keep getting the document, before I pass it to the transaction to get it again.

Comment: Hey Doug.  I've re-engineered my code to allow for _out of sequence_ functions.  However, I also found the retry method that I'd seen documented somewhere, previously.  For reference (and I haven't tried implementing it), the method is [firestoreClient.beginTransaction](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/FirestoreClient#beginTransaction) and the [retry option](https://googleapis.github.io/gax-nodejs/global.html#CallOptions)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that retry option, nor anything else in the doc you linked to.  Are you sure that applies to Firestore?

Comment: I use quite a few things from the nodejs documentation, like .getAll and .parent. is an excellent resource. Clement from the Firestore backend team introduced me to it

Comment: Well, if you have everything you need, you can answer your own question here with all the details that someone else would need to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two options for your problem:

### 1. Use the Google Cloud RETRY flag

When you deploy a function you can simply enable retries, which will lead to the google-cloud environment automatically invoking your function if it throws **any error** (or returns rejected Promise) This sounds quite good, until you realise this may create **!significant charges!**, because if you have a bug in your function, which throws an error every time, the function will be called thousands of times until the retry-limit is finally exceeded after a day or two.

Your function could look like this:

```
return t.get(myDocumentRef)
    .then(doc => {
        if ((newState = 'stage2' && doc.data().state = 'stage1') ||
            (newState = 'stage3' && doc.data().state = 'stage2')) {
          t.update(myDocumentRef, { population: newPopulation });
        } else {
          throw new Error('Illegal state') 
        }
    });
}).then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
    if (event.timeStamp < Date.now()-300000) {
        // We have tried for 5 minutes and still an error, we give up
        console.error('Bad things happen: ', err)
    } else {
        throw new Error(err) // Firebase will receive this as a rejected Promise and retry
    }
})
```

### 2. Create your own retry logic

If you just want a single retry after some time, you can simply return a Promise which will resolve via setTimeout() to wait a short amount of time and try again. This looks like a little more work, but you have a lot more control over the number of retries. But in contrast to the Firebase retries you will have to deal with the maximum runtime-limit of your function.

```
else {
  return new Promise(r => window.setTimeout(tryUpdate, 100))
```